# WSQ files not opening with Pillow/wsq when using joblib.Parallel

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, joblib

I am trying to preprocess large amounts of [WSQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_scalar_quantization) images for model training using both the Pillow and wsq libraries. To speed up my code, I am trying to use Parallel but this causes an UnidentifiedImageError.

I verified that the files are there where they should be, and that the function runs without errors when used in a regular for-loop. Other files (eg csv files) can be opened inside the function without errors, so I presume that the error lies with the combination of Parallel and Pillow/wsq. All libraries are up to date. As I am just starting out with Pillow and multiprocessing, I have no idea yet on how to fix this and any help would be highly appreciated.

Code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from PIL import Image
import multiprocessing
import wsq
import numpy as np

def process_image(i):
    path = "/home/user/project/wsq/image_"+str(i)+".wsq"
    img = np.array(Image.open(path))
    #some preprocessing, saving as npz
    output_path = "/home/user/project/npz/image_"+str(i)+".npz"
    np.savez_compressed(output_path, img)

    return None

inputs = range(100000)
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(process_image)(i) for i in inputs)
```

Output:

```
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 431, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 285, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "preprocess_images.py", line 9, in process_image
    img = np.array(Image.open(path))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2967, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/home/user/project/wsq/image_1.wsq'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocess_images.py", line 18, in <module>
    Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(process_image)(i) for i in inputs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1054, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 933, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 542, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/home/user/project/wsq/image_1.wsq'
```

Comment: What happens if you run `file /home/user/project/wsq/image_1.wsq` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Just what you would expect, I think. Output: `/home/user/project/wsq/image_1.wsq:  Wavelet Scalar Quantization image data`

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it is/was unhelpful and may deter others from answering. Good luck with your question - let's hope someone else can help. Providing a link to a WSQ file may facilitate things...

Comment: The open source WSQ implementations you'll find online are not thread safe, so you'll never get them to work with a joblib.Parallel. You'll just get corrupts images and/or crashes.